# Jest failed to parse component library containing MUI components

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vite

I am trying to set up Jest with react-testing-library in my Vite TypeScript repository.
I am importing a local, company-intern React component library that utilizes MUI components and re-export them. This library is installed via npm.

While resolving, Jest cannot find this module.
However, when using a module mapper, I encounter the following error:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

Jest encountered an unexpected token

Jest failed to parse a file. This happens e.g. when your code or its dependencies use non-standard JavaScript syntax, or when Jest is not configured to support such syntax.

Out of the box Jest supports Babel, which will be used to transform your files into valid JS based on your Babel configuration.

By default "node_modules" folder is ignored by transformers.


Details:

/home/user/source/apps/portal/saas-cloud-service-manager-next/app/saas-csm-web/node_modules/@my-org/portal-ui/build/portal-ui.js:1
({"Object.<anonymous>":function(module,exports,require,__dirname,__filename,jest){import { jsx as w, jsxs as i, Fragment as Q } from "react/jsx-runtime";
                                                                                  ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

  1 | import { Container, Grid, Skeleton, Stack, Typography } from '@mui/material';
> 2 | import { EmptyContent, useMultiTenant } from '@my-org/portal-ui';
    | ^
  3 | import { AxiosError } from 'axios';
  4 | import { debounce } from 'lodash';
  5 | import NProgress from 'nprogress';

  at Runtime.createScriptFromCode (node_modules/jest-runtime/build/index.js:1505:14)
  at Object.require (src/pages/Overview/Overview.tsx:2:1)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/pages/Overview/Overview.test.tsx:3:1)
```

My Setup looks the follows:

**jest.config.ts**

```
import type { Config } from 'jest';

const config: Config = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@my-org/portal-ui$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@my-org/portal-ui/build/portal-ui.js',
  },
};

export default config;
```

**src/tests/setupTests.ts**

```
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2020",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["ES2020", "DOM", "DOM.Iterable"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "skipLibCheck": true,

    /* Bundler mode */
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "allowImportingTsExtensions": true,
    // "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",

    /* Linting */
    "strict": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "types": ["@testing-library/jest-dom"],
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}
```

Can someone help me how to resolve the internal component library with Jest tests?

Comment: Jest not natively support ES module syntax. In your Jest configuration, ensure that you are using babel-jest to transpile ES modules

Comment: i've tried to set babelrc up the follows:

`{
  "presets": [
    ["@babel/preset-env", { "targets": { "node": "current" } }],
    "@babel/preset-react",
    "@babel/preset-typescript",
  ],
}`


jest.config.ts
`testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/tests/setupTests.ts'],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@my-org/portal-ui$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/@my-org/portal-ui/build/portal-ui.js',
  },
  transform: {
    '\\.[jt]sx?$': 'babel-jest',
  },
`

Does not work ...